# ¿Cómo imprimir números con separador de miles en Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy realizando prácticas con QtDesigner y PyQt5, cuestión, que busco que al determinar el salario bruto y neto de una persona, junto con sus descuentos, enseñe estos valores con decimal
Por ejemplo:
Si una persona gana 10$ por cada 120 horas de trabajo, que muestre en el text edit "1.200" y no solo "1200"
Adjunto código:

```
import sys 
from salario import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ventana(QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui=Ui_Frm1()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.BtnAceptar.clicked.connect(self.Aceptar)




  def Aceptar(self):
        hr=self.ui.Txthoras.toPlainText()
        pago=self.ui.Txtpago.toPlainText()
        hr=int(hr)
        pago=int(pago)
        bruto=hr*pago
        descuento=bruto*0.2
        neto=bruto-descuento

        self.ui.TxtBruto.setText(str(bruto))
        self.ui.TxtDescuento.setText(str(descuento))
        self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))




if __name__== "__main__":
        mi_aplicacion= QApplication(sys.argv)
        mi_app = Ventana()
        mi_app.show()
        sys.exit(mi_aplicacion.exec_())
```

Comment: Pruébalo `print(f'{1200:0,.2f}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres separar cualquier número por **miles**, aunque no llege a la cifra, el código a usar es:

```
valor = 1200
dinero = '{:,}'.format(valor)
# resultado => 1,200
```

Si decides remplazar la coma, por un punto, se debería utilizar la expresión:

```
dinero = '{:,}'.format(valor).replace(',','.')
print(dinero)
# resultado => 1.200
```

Así cualquier numero que pases mayor de mil, tendrá formato, si utilizas cientos de miles como por ejemplo `123456`, el resultado será *123,456*

Otra opción es, que este formato dependa de la ***ubicación del usuario***, para esto, se usaría el módulo `locale`

```
import locale
ubicacion = locale.getlocale() # obtenemos el código del país
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ubicacion) # establecemos la ubicación
dinero = '{:,d}'.format(valor) # formato según la ubicación obtenida
# resultado => 1,200 (en caso de es_ES, definido a España)
```